# Rearranging nested list in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, nested-lists

I have a list:
`list1 = {{{3, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}, {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}};`
From the list above I would like to obtain a following list:
`{{{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}}}`
I have tried to use ArrayReshape, but the resulting list is not what I desired:
`list2 = ArrayReshape[list1, {1, 3, 8}]`
`{{{3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}}}`
*edit
Desired solution should generalize to lists with all inputs being different.
**edit
Example of a list for general case:
`{{{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3},{c1,c2,c3}},{{d1,d2,d3},{e1,e2,e3},{f1,f2,f3}}}`
And desired outcome:
`{{{a1,a2,a3,d1,d2,d3},{b1,b2,b3,e1,e2,e3},{c1,c2,c3,f1,f2,f3}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
list1 = {{{3,3,3,3},{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2}},{{3,3,3,3},{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2}}}; 
f[v_]:=Table[v,{Count[Flatten[list1],v]}]
Map[f,DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[list1]]]
```

which instantly returns

```
{{3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}}
```

EDIT

Is there any chance that this is what you were looking for?

```
list1 = {{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}},
         {{13,14,15,16},{17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24}}};
MapThread[Join,list1]
```

which returns

```
{{1,2,3,4,13,14,15,16},{5,6,7,8,17,18,19,20},{9,10,11,12,21,22,23,24}}
```

Just guessing

Comment: Thanks! I guess i haven`t been explicit about the problem. How would this generalize to inputs of list not being the same? Say all inputs of the list1 would`ve been different.